# VPN juniper Mac firefox

Tags: networking, macos, mac, firefox, juniper

I am unable to connect to my company using VPN on my Mac.

Mac version: EL Capitan Firefox version: 38.0.1 Java version on firefox as verified Version 8 Update 66.

When I am trying to connect, the following screen came up and just hang there.

Here is the exact message:

`Loading Components...
Please wait. This may take several minutes.
    •   Host Checker`

Thanks Tin

Comment: You should contact your company's tech support..

Comment: The company doesn't support Mac. They only support IE...

Comment: Then I'm thinking they need to provide you with a company computer :P

Answer (score 1):

1. there are numerous VPN formats/types.  Have you confirmed that the version provided is the version you're attempting to use?  LT2P, PPTP, OpenVPN, etc...
2. do you have the credentials correct?
3. do you have the correct IP address?
4. are you outside the network when attempting to connect (if you're "inside", it's not going to work)?

Remember that VPN is essentially a process whereby your netadmin folks hand you the user, a pair of keys to the company Ferrari, with little/no supervision. You would do well to tread softly, ask politely, and WHATEVER YOU DO, don't tick them off..

You've likely already gotten things off to a rocky start if you're expecting them to help you trouble-shoot your pet OS issue, when they are only paid to manage the fiasco of IE...

Comment: I used to have VPN working on my mac with an earlier version of Java. I think it's Java 7 update 40 with mavericks.. I've upgraded to EI Capitan and latest Java... which made VPN stop working... It's frustrating as I can't downgrade my java either... so I am stuck...